# Probability, 8 blackboards assigned to 4 schools

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem in the title is a common problem as I see. I have problem to understand the problem, even if I know what to use to solve it, because I don't know why I should use it.

The problem is that we have 8 blackboards to assigned to 4 schools. How many ways do we have to share them into the 4 schools?

I know that the answer should be:

\begin{equation}
\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}
\end{equation}

Where $r=4$ and $n=8$. My question is, why is this the answer to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line up the blackboards with three partitions between them.  The boards before the first partition are to go to the first school. The boards between the first and second partition are to be sent to the second school on the list. And so forth.

There are $n$ boards and $r-1$ partions.   ( *Note:* the boards themselves are indistinguishable, and there's no need to distinguish between partitions. )   Count how many ways there are to arrange these.

That count is $\dbinom{n+r-1}{r-1} = \dfrac{(n+r-1)!}{n!\,(r-1)!}$

This is known as the "stars and bars" method.   So named after the way to count arrangements of $n$ stars and $r-1$ bars, to count distinct ways to arrange $n$ identical balls into $r$ boxes; the bars represent partitions between boxes.